# How to play audio while animation in unity 3D?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm new unity 3D developer i want to play audio while animation at the time set. How to play audio while animation in unity 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AnimationEvents](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) to call a function at a specific frame in an
 animation it can be playing an audio or anything else